# Run a command via ssh with Shelly/Turtle

Tags: bash, haskell, ssh, haskell-turtle, shelly

Given a command:

```
ssh user@host command
```

where `command`, when executed on the remote host `host`, should be:

```
somecmd --option1 'option value with spaces' 'arg1 with spaces' 'arg2 with weird chars, like ('
```

How can I execute this command using the [Haskell Shelly](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shelly)
or the [Haskell Turtle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle)?

Shelly provides a `sshPairs`, but it didn't quote `command` correctly.

Quoting in a bash script can be fragile, does these two libraries, (or any Haskell libraries, for that matter),
tries to improve this?

Comment: Note that this has been fixed in the latest version of Shelly:https://github.com/yesodweb/Shelly.hs/issues/146

Comment: @Sibi not really, see [here](https://github.com/yesodweb/Shelly.hs/pull/147#issuecomment-349934385)

Comment: Ah okay. I will look into it. Note that other option for use is shell-conduit: https://github.com/psibi/shell-conduit ( Disclosure: I'm it's current maintainer)

Comment: If `sshPairs` doesn't do quoting correctly, you could try to implement the correct quoting yourself and then run the command with a more primitive functionality, like [`shell`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.4.5/docs/Turtle-Prelude.html#v:shell). Also note that the documentation on `sshPairs` explicitly states: "the commands will not be shell escaped". Neither library attempts to solve the problem of fragility of shell quoting (indeed, trying to solve this problem in a shell interop lib doesn't make sense, since there are so many different shells out there)

Comment: @user2407038 guess have to do it manually then